# Extract specific variables from a mixed string/JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I am using [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) with a custom AngularJS directive that I built, Tagify mixed input returns the JSON objects of selected tags and text in one single string, for example:

```
var tagify = new Tagify(myElement, {
    mode: 'mix',
    pattern: /@/,
    whitelist: [{ value: "User Name", code: '$name' }, { value: "Phone Number", code: '$phone' }],
    enforceWhitelist: true,
    dropdown: {
        maxItems: 20,
        classname: "tags-look",
        enabled: 0,
        closeOnSelect: true
    }
});
tagify.on('change', () => console.log(tagify.DOM.input.value))
```

The user input would be:

> Hello `User Name ×`, the SMS has been sent to your phone `Phone Number ×`.

This simple example returns:

> Hello `[[{ value: "User Name", code: '$name' }]]`, the SMS has been
> sent to your phone `[[{ value: "Phone Number", code: '$phone' }]]`.
> (and the JSON returned is escaped)

What I am doing later is replacing the tags that the user selected (by typing the `@` character and selecting them from the dropdown) with my own dynamic variables.

I was able to get a nice result with `tagify.DOM.input.textContent` as it rendered the following result:

> Hello User Name, the SMS has been sent to your phone Phone Number.

However, since the `whitelist` is translatable and can be in other languages that I can't `find and replace` easily later, what I need is the `code` attribute from the JSON whitelist and not the `value`. The expected result that I couldn't find a way to reach yet is:

> `Hello $name, the SMS has been sent to your phone $phone`.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your request.

Comment: You said that with  `tagify.DOM.input.textContent` you were able to generate `Hello User Name, the SMS has been sent to your phone Phone Number`. Can you post the code you wrote for that.

Comment: Simply using `tagify.DOM.input.textContent` returns the mentioned result!

Comment: [https://codesandbox.io/s/tagify-react-wrapper-forked-dfo29?file=/src/index.js]

Comment: By "can't find and replace easily later" do you mean you don't want to do modify this "Hello [[{ value: "User Name", code: '$name' }]], the SMS has been sent to your phone [[{ value: "Phone Number", code: '$phone' }]]" ->  to this  -> "Hello $name, the SMS has been sent to your phone $phone." ?

Comment: If English was the only language of my app, I could str.replace("Phone Number", "+9053xxxxxx"), but since my app is localized into 5 languages, and I have a lot of variables, i used the JSON format of Tagify, all I need is extracting the `code` parameter from the `tagify.DOM.input.value` result.

Answer (score 7):

You can create your custom transform function, to transform it the way you like, you can do something like this.

```
function transformer(value) {
    return value.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, (arr => {
     let json = JSON.parse(arr);
     return json[0].map(e => e.code).join(', ');
    }))
 }
```

And then you can call it on change (or rather on/or before submit), like this:

```
tagify.on('change', (e) => transformer(e.detail.value));
```

Comment: Please note that `e.target.value` should be `e.detail.value`